# Strange Linq issue

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What's the difference between the following two? The first 1 works but the 2nd one errors out stating that 'Select' cannot be found.  I can't understand why.

1st:

```
Office Office = 
    cHelper.Offices
           .Where(o => o.IP3rdOctet  == OSHelper.Get3rdOctetOfMyIP())
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

2nd:

```
Office Office = 
    from o in cHelper.Offices
                     .Where(o => o.IP3rdOctet == OSHelper.Get3rdOctetOfMyIP())
                     .FirstOrDefault()
    select o;
```

Comment: Not sure why you're doing a from/select when you're already getting a firstordefault.

Comment: Not sure why are mixing different styles (query syntax vs Extension method syntax)

Comment: Both concepts compile for me using List<string> !

Comment: @Spacebison: try to use List<Office> it wouldn't work. i think it is call normal inference type for method argument ?

Comment: @SpaceBison A string may be queried as a collection of characters. An Office may not be queried - The Office may have collections, but it is not acting as a collection.  Due to this, the call to Select cannot resolve (neither Enumerable.Select nor Queryable.Select apply, and office didn't implement Select itself).

Comment: @DavidB +1 - a very valid point indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not** an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, it is an instance of `Office`:

```
cHelper.Offices.Where(o => o.IP3rdOctet 
                == OSHelper.Get3rdOctetOfMyIP()).FirstOrDefault()
```

You cannot call `select` on that. Remove the call to `FirstOrDefault()`, then you will be able to select the results (which will be empty if no items match your criteria).

If you then still need the `FirstOrDefault` item, then put the query in brackets and append `FirstOrDefault()` like this:

```
Office Office = (from o in cHelper.Offices
                 where o.IP3rdOctet == OSHelper.Get3rdOctetOfMyIP()
                 select o).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

`select` works with an `IEnumerable`, you are trying to use select after `FirstOrDefault`

rewrite like this:

```
Office Office = (from o in cHelper.Offices
                where o.IP3rdOctet == OSHelper.Get3rdOctetOfMyIP()
                select o).FirstOrDefault();
```